# javascript firebase.auth().currentUser = null

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I've create a simple login.js with method signinwithemailandpassword(email,password) by firebase.auth().
after correct login, by the method window.open("homepage.html"), i open a new page.
in this homepage if i use window.alert(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid), i have error because currenUser is null.
I'm tring to use a observer

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.

    var uid = user.uid;

  } else {
   // User is signed out.
   // ...
  }
});
```

but this observer check if exist or not the user, don't take me a method for retrieve uid user or store correct it.

Comment: Using an `onAuthStateChanged` listener is the proper way to detect if the user is signed in. Inside it you can `window.alert(uid)` to see the UID of the user. But I don't understand what you're trying to do inside of that code, that you're having trouble with. It may help if you show the actual code that you're trying to use inside this callback.

Answer (score 0):

Login.js

```
const txtemail = document.getElementById('input_email');
const txtpassword = document.getElementById('input_password');
const btnLogin = document.getElementById('buttonLogin');

btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
const email = txtemail.value;
const password = txtpassword.value;
 if(email == ""){
   window.alert("inserisci email!");
  } else if (password == ""){
    window.alert("inserisci Password");
  } else {

 const auth = firebase.auth();
 auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
 }
});


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
 if (user) {
firebase.database().ref("TeamLavoro").orderByChild('Email').equalTo(user.email).on("value", function(snapshot) {
  if(snapshot.val() != null){
      window.open("homepageteam.html", "_self");
  } else {
      window.open("homepage.html", "_self");
   }
 })
  }else{
   window.alert("Nessun Utente Trovato");
 }
});
```

homepageteam.js

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
if(user){
  window.alert(user.uid);
}
else{
  window.alert("No USER")
}
});
```

all of time "NO USER".
I've try with .than and .catch, but is equal.